# Unable to find an element in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

error occurred(missing element) in both ways :

```
ele3=d.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='tel'][type='data-v-094823ec']")

ele3=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Please enter your phone number']")
```

webpage element:
[image: webpage element]

Comment: what is the error for `ele3=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Please enter your phone number']") ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the CSS selector,

`input[name='tel'][type='data-v-094823ec']`

should be

`input[type='tel'][data-v-094823ec]`

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='van-dropdown-menu']/input[@type='tel']")
```